# Question about a counterexample related to the mean value theorem for integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions

Let $g(x) = x$ on the interval $[ 1, 3]$. Can you find a function $f (x)$ such that no value between the minimum and maximum of $f (x$) satisfies
$$
\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x) dx \,=\, \alpha\int_{a}^{b}g(x) dx \,?
$$

Comment: Do you want $a=1$ and $b=3$? If not, what are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: this questin will be solved by mean value theorem for Riemann integrals.However, I can not reach the solution. I was a lof of mistake.Do you know the answer to this question?can you help me?

Comment: yes a=1 and b=3

Comment: So what you really want is a function $f(x)$ defined on $[1,3]$ such that $$\int_1^3xf(x)dx\ne\alpha\int_1^3xdx=4\alpha$$ for each $\alpha$ between the minimum and maximum values of $x$ on $[1,3]$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I think they mean the minimum and maximum values of $f$, not $x$.

Comment: @Julien: So did I: that was a typo.

Comment: @user70657 Do you want $f$ to be continuous, or can it be any function?

Comment: @JulienClancy I don't know f is continuous or not. my teacher asked  me in this way

Comment: @BrianM.Scott why did integrals not equal.I don't understand.

Comment: The problem asks you to find $f$ so that no matter what $\alpha$ you choose between $\min f(x)$ and $\max f(x)$, the equation $$\int_1^3xf(x)dx=\alpha\int_1^3xdx=4\alpha$$ is **not** true. In other words, for all such $\alpha$ you must have $$\int_1^3xf(x)dx\ne\alpha\int_1^3xdx\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = 1$ if $x \in [1,2]$, $f(x) = 0$ if $x \in [2,3]$. It's not hard to show that $\int_1^3 xf(x) = \pi \int_1^3 x = \frac{3}{2}$. We know that the only values of $f$ are $0$ and $1$, neither of which satisfy $4\alpha = \frac{3}{2}$. This is assuming that you want $\alpha$ to be in the range of $f$.

If you don't want $\alpha$ in the range of $f$, i.e. you're just concerned with it being between the maximum and minimum values, you're not going to be able to find such an $f$. The intuition behind the argument is that you "normalize" $f$ so that it's continuous, call the normalization $f_0$, with $\int_1^3 xf = \int_1^3 xf_0$ with $f_0$ achieves the maximum and minimum of $f$. Then you apply the mean value theorem to conclude.

Edit: Never mind, this is far easier than my solution. We have the inequalities

$\int_1^3 x \min f(x) \leq \int_1^3 xf(x) \leq \int_1^3 x \max f(x)$

and we wish to satisfy $4\alpha = \int_1^3 xf(x)$ for some $\min f(x) \leq \alpha \leq \max f(x)$. The result easily follows by continuity of the integral.

Comment: I understand what you say.and I know this questin can be solved by mean value theorem.I found $$ \frac{f(1)}{4\alpha}\le f(x)\le \frac{f(3)}{4\alpha} $$ .however I don't know it is true.